# How to use Wobly serializer on Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm looking for the alternatives to serialize objects in my Android project. I found [Wobly](http://code.google.com/p/wobly/) which seem to be fast and small. I understand how to create `Wobly` wrappers using `WoblyImpl` but I'm totally confused with **how to write/read these objects from the file system**? When to run `WoblyGenerator` and can it be done within my code? Can someone post a code example?

Comment: Have you tried Gson? It's very simple and customizable.

Comment: I'm happy with json-smart, and the question is not about which JSON lib to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wobly doesn't support unknown Object fields. So fields like:

```
Object a;
List<Object> b;
Map<Integer, Object> c;
```

cannot be serialized with Wobly.
It supports all primitive classes (and their boxed counterparts), all Wobly classes, any Array/List/Map combination of the above.

So in your case, problem is that `JSONArray` implements `List<Object>`. If you know what kind of object `JSONArray` holds, for example `List<Map<Integer, String>>`, you can write:

```
class Example extends WoblyImpl {
  @WoblyField(id = 0)
  List<Map<Integer, String>> array;

  public void setArray(JSONArray json) {
    array = (List)json;
  }
}
```

Though after deserialization you will get `ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,String>>` and not `JSONArray` back.

If you don't know what object `JSONArray` is holding, it would be painful to make it work with Wobly, if at all possible. You can check out comprehensive comparison of serialization libraries here:
https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki

Comment: Obviously it doesn't hold one type of the object. Mostly Strings but the other primitives and JSONArrays as well. Thanks for your reply, I'll try to research the alternatives

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. If you wondered here and want to know how to do it here are the steps:

1. Create your class by extending WoblyImpl and annotate the fields according to [the instructions](http://code.google.com/p/wobly/)
2. Then run `WoblyGenerator.updateSourceFolder("c:/foo/src");` where the parameter is directory containing your file (or package). I created a small project in Eclipse for that but you can also run this from the command line using supplied wobly-generator.jar
3. This step will inject serialization code into your source file which will include read and write methods
4. **Gotcha**: this didn't work for smart-json JSONObject or JSONArray or for HashMap. The error I got is this:

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: next type for class net.minidev.json.JSONObject of  index 0, class java.lang.Class
   at  com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyGeneratorUtils.extractNextType(WoblyGeneratorUtils.java:91)
   at   com.wowd.wobly.generation.types.impl.MapTypeCodeGenerator.defaultTypeFormat(MapTypeCodeGenerator.java:163)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.types.TypeCodeHandler.defaultTypeFormat(TypeCodeHandler.java:121)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyGeneratorUtils.adjusFormatForCompressed(WoblyGeneratorUtils.java:317)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyCodeGenerator.generateWriteFieldCode(WoblyCodeGenerator.java:178)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyCodeGenerator.generateWriteMethod(WoblyCodeGenerator.java:270)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyCodeGenerator.generateFieldsAndMethods(WoblyCodeGenerator.java:647)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyCodeGenerator.generateRegularCode(WoblyCodeGenerator.java:721)
   at com.wowd.wobly.generation.WoblyCodeGenerator.generateCode(WoblyCodeGenerator.java:677)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.GenerateAndReplace.update(GenerateAndReplace.java:130)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.GenerateAndReplace$1.execute(GenerateAndReplace.java:198)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.GenerateAndReplace$1.execute(GenerateAndReplace.java:1)
   at com.wowd.common.functions.impl.FilterProcedure.execute(FilterProcedure.java:40)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.SourceFilesVisitor.visitDir(SourceFilesVisitor.java:69)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.SourceFilesVisitor.visitDir(SourceFilesVisitor.java:60)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.SourceFilesVisitor.visitDir(SourceFilesVisitor.java:60)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.SourceFilesVisitor.visitDir(SourceFilesVisitor.java:60)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.SourceFilesVisitor.visitPackage(SourceFilesVisitor.java:38)
   at com.wowd.wobly.updater.GenerateAndReplace.updateInPackage(GenerateAndReplace.java:190)    WoblyParcel                             error

   at com.wowd.wobly.WoblyGenerator.updatePackage(WoblyGenerator.java:60)
   at com.wowd.wobly.WoblyGenerator.updateSourceFolder(WoblyGenerator.java:49)
   at Generator.main(Generator.java:19)
   ```

If someone can tell me how to fix that - post it as a separate answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Can you give an example of the class that fails serialization? HashMap should be supported out of the box. 
JSONObject and JSONArray are little trickier, because they use different kind of serialization. Do you want to serialize those fields as json strings, or as if JSONArray was a regular array?

Comment: Yes, sure. Both classes are from json-smart. JSONObject http://goo.gl/1Ho6Q and JSONArray http://goo.gl/jeih7

Comment: Ideally I want fully deserialized combination of JSONObjects and JSONArrays (whichever happens to be the top object) But I'll take it as stripped down mix of plain HashMaps and Arrays